# Alternative to V divider for high currents

Tags: voltage-divider, zener, gate-driving

I am looking for suggestions as to how to supply power to a gate drive optocoupler i am using.

The supply being used is a 25V (rms) ac supply and intend to supply 10V DC at around 500mA+ from my supply. 
When i have reduced the voltage, i will maintain it with some caps.

I was looking for an alternative to a high power resistor divider. I thought about a zener diode and i am aware of high power zeners, though this would still need a high power resistor to limit the current.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i am trying to use small components with a single supply (500VA toroidal).

Answer (score 1):

I think that a full-wave bridge rectifier feeding a bulk storage capacitor which then feeds a DC-DC buck converter will work nicely for you.  You can purchase a ready-made DC-DC buck converter from eBay for less than $10 and the bridge rectifier and storage capacitor will set you back another $10 or so.

Comment: i have a rectifier and some high power diodes, so i am missing the dc-dc convertor.

Comment: [This could work](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/5pcs-LM2596S-DC-DC-Buck-Converter-Adjustable-Power-Supply-Step-Down-Module-UK-/141210161794?pt=UK_BOI_Electrical_Test_Measurement_Equipment_ET&hash=item20e0c81282)
looks like i could use some smoothing caps to input a relatively stabe DC voltage around the 34v peak of my supply. 
Seems like it will also handle my current requirements too. 

WHats the verdict?

Comment: One thing to be aware of is that the loading characteristics of rectifier / capacitor circuits sometimes create problems. All of the current is conducted at the peaks when the rectifier diodes are forward biased. This is not necessarily a reason to avoid this topology. I am just pointing it out.

Comment: could you elaborate a little? 
Both as to what you mean and its ramifications in my application. 

Thanks!

Comment: Suppose you have an AC source, and the only thing loading it is a full bridge rectifier followed by large capacitors followed by some kind of DC or DC-ish load. During the majority of the AC cycle, the current is zero because the rectifiers are reverse biased. When the rectified voltage exceeds the DC rail voltage, then the rectifier starts to conduct for a brief period when the AC voltage is near a maximum or minimum. So if there is 1 Watt of DC power getting eaten up, ignoring diodes and such, there is 1W of AC power going in...

Comment: but that AC power is all dumped in during a short percentage  of each AC cycle. This behavior can be problematic for some AC sources. In your case, you only need half an Ampere, and the transformer is 500VA, so I suspect it will be OK.

Comment: Understood, thanks for sharing that. 
The dc that I am deriving from the AC source is to supply a gate drive opto-coupler, the mosfet being driven will be conducting AC from the same source. So at the moments when the gate driver is demanding 10V@500ma from the cap/supply, the load will be pulling around 15-7 amps. 
As you said, i think for my set-up, this shouldn't be problematic.

Comment: Can i possibly ask someone to clarify that the switched mode power supply being used in the dc-dc convertor won't try to compensate for the output voltage being sunk by the gate driver opto?
If the output of the DC-DC is monitored to maintain a stale current/voltage - will switching it at high frequency not foul this somewhat?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capacitive dropper, rectifier and a zener diode or, if the load is quite stable you should be able to get away without the zener. Here are a couple of examples from the internet: -

[image]

As you are using this for only 25VAC there's no real need to warn you about how dangerous these are when used on AC power directly from the socket.

Same principal - the capacitor reduces the voltage without incurring heavy power losses and producing heat.

Comment: i just read that electrolytics arent used for this purpose. 
That had me confused until i clarified that haha. 
Thanks. ill look into it!